# ¿Como evitar que phpexcel me almacene los registros de un ciclo en un archivo distinto?

Tags: codeigniter-3, phpexcel

En un primer método traigo una consulta el cual armo en un `arreglo` para pasarlo al segundo método quien sera el que me 'armara' un archivo `excel`.

**EL PROBLEMA**

Cuando el primer método ejecuta el segundo método en su primera 'vuelta o loop' el archivo de `excel` sale perfectamente pero cuando hace la segunda vuelta para descargar el segundo archivo de `excel`, parece que este almacenara los datos datos del archivo anterior con los nuevos registros que estoy intentando descargar el cual no tiene nada que ver, en pocas palabras el segundo archivo me combina la información con la del primer archivo, ¿porque sucede esto?, ¿Es algún problema del phpexcel que almacena información?

**CODIGO**

```
 public function sendMessage(){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
        $this->load->library(['phpmailer_lib','conexion']); 

        $resp = $this->Send_model->getMessages();

        for ($i=0; $i < count($resp); $i++):

            if($resp[$i]->rep_status):
                $data[$i] = [
                    'cli_name' =>  $resp[$i]->cli_name,
                    'cli_id'   =>  $resp[$i]->cli_id,
                    'host'     =>  $resp[$i]->cli_host,
                    'user'     =>  $resp[$i]->cli_user,
                    'pass'     =>  $resp[$i]->cli_pass,
                    'dbname'   =>  $resp[$i]->cli_database,                             
                    'port'     =>  $resp[$i]->cli_port,
                    'driver'   =>  $resp[$i]->cli_driver,
                ];   

                $datos[$i] = [
                    'reporte'  =>  $resp[$i]->rep_nombre_reporte,
                    'extension' =>  $resp[$i]->rep_extension_file
                ];

                if($this->conexion->connect($data[$i])): 
                    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($resp[$i]->rep_query);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result[$i] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);            
                    $this->testdownload($datos[$i], $result[$i]);
                endif;
            endif;
        endfor;
    }

 public function testdownload($datos, $result){

        $this->load->library(['excel']);    

        // Aqui saco el nombre de las columnas
        $columns = [];
        foreach ($result[0] as $key => $value):
            $columns[] = $key; 
        endforeach;


        $this->excel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none"); 
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        // Aqui creo las cabeceras en los campos de excel en la primera fila
        $col = 0;
        for ($fi=0; $fi < count($columns); $fi++):            
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $columns[$fi]);
            $col++;
        endfor;


        // Aqui ya recorro todos los registros y les asigno a que columna pertenecen
        $row = 2;          
        for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { 

            $column = 0;
            for ($c=0; $c < count($columns); $c++) { 
                    $datas = $columns[$c];
                    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $result[$i]->$datas);
                $column++;
            }   

            $row++;
        }

        $ext = '';
        switch ($datos['extension']):
            case 'xlsx':
                $ext = 'Excel2007';
                break;

            case 'csv':
                $ext = 'CSV';
                break;
        endswitch;

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, $ext);

        $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $datos['reporte']);
        $objWriter->save('./reportes/'.$filename.'.'.$datos['extension']);

        $this->conexion->close_con();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver mi problema, al parecer la librería `PHPExcel` acumula la información cuando existe un ciclo un `for`, por tal motivo en cada bucle se debe 'destruir' el objeto de `PHPExcel` usando el siguiente código..

```
$ objPHPExcel-> disconnectWorksheets (); 
$ objPHPExcel-> garbageCollect (); 
unset ($ objPHPExcel);
```